# Understanding "End of support", "Deprecated," and "Decommission" States for Node.js Versions (Jan 30, 2024)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I am seeking a detailed understanding of the meanings behind the states "End of support", "Deprecated," and "Decommission" for Node.js versions on Google Cloud Platform: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/support-schedule?hl=en#nodejs

Here is the alert message I have on my App Engine instances using Node.js version 12: "Node.js 12 will no longer be supported after Jan 30, 2024. We recommend upgrading to the latest version of the Node.js runtime as soon as possible."

Could you assist me in comprehending each of these states and what they imply for deploying applications on App Engine?

I want to clarify that I am well aware that I need to migrate my application to a higher version of Node.js (specifically, at least version 18), but I want to understand the schedule in advance to better organize with my team.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

I think this GPC documentation could help you quite a bit: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/runtime-lifecycle?hl=en#fnref1